# SQL - Sum of multiple rows with considering to type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
+========================================================+
|    Number   |    Date     |    Liter    |     Type      |
+=========================================================+
|       1     | 2018-11-01  |      1.0    |       A       |
|       2     | 2018-11-01  |      2.0    |       A       |
|       3     | 2018-11-01  |      3.0    |       B       |
|       1     | 2018-11-02  |      4.0    |    NULL       |
|       2     | 2018-11-02  |      5.0    |       B       |
|       3     | 2018-11-02  |      6.0    |    NULL       |
|       1     | 2018-11-03  |      7.0    |       B       |
|       2     | 2018-11-03  |      8.0    |       B       |
|       3     | 2018-11-03  |      9.0    |    NULL       |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

And i need something this, with `WHERE Date LIKE '2018-11-%'`

```
+========================================================+
|  Number  |  SumOfTypeA  |  SumOfTypeB  |  SumOfTypeNULL |
+=========================================================+
|     1    |      1.0     |      7.0     |       4.0      |
|     2    |      2.0     |     13.0     |      NULL      |
|     3    |     NULL     |      3.0     |      15.0      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas for do this query?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation using `SUM()` and `CASE..WHEN` expressions:

```
SELECT
  Number,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN Liter END) AS SumOfTypeA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Liter END) AS SumOfTypeB,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type IS NULL THEN Liter END) AS SumOfTypeNull
FROM your_table
WHERE Date LIKE '2018-11-%'
GROUP BY Number
```